# Chrome Extension: How to change headers on every page request programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, header, response

I'm currently developing a Chrome Extension and need to add/change a header value, but only on a specific page. Something like this:

```
chrome.onPageRequest(function(host) {
    if(host == 'google.com') {
        chrome.response.addHeader('X-Auth', 'abc123');
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the **[chrome.webRequest API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)** for that purpose. You'll need the following:

1. Declare the appropriate permissions in your manifest:

   ```
   ...
   "permissions": [
       ...
       "webRequest",
       "*://*.google.com/*"
   ]
   ```
2. Register a listener for the **[`chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onHeadersReceived)** event and modify the headers. In order to be able to modify the headers, you need to define the 'responseHeaders' extra info (see 3rd arguments of listener function):

   ```
   chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
       console.log(details);
       details.responseHeaders.push({
           name: 'X-Auth',
           value: 'abc123'
       });
       return { responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders };
   }, {
       urls: ['*://*.google.com/*']
   }, [
       "responseHeaders"
   ]);
   ```
3. Keep in mind that the `webRequest` permission only works if your background-page is persistent, so remove the corresponding line from your manifest (if it exists - which it should):

   ```
   ...
   "background": {
       "persistent": false,   // <-- Remove this line or set it to `true`
       "scripts": [...]
       ...
   ```

---

Also, keep in mind that pretty often Google redirects requests based on the user's country (e.g. redirecting `www.google.com` to `www.google.gr`), in which case the filter will not let them reach your `onHeadersReceived` listener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've implemented it. The event is firing, but when I dump the headers with `print_r(apache_request_headers());`, I don't see the header attached. Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: You said you wanted to modify the response headers (and that is what the code in my answer does). You are checking the request headers with `print_r(apache_request_headers());`, so there is nothing changed there. What is that you want to achieve after all ?

Comment: Exactly, I want to set an additional header when the user browses e.g. google.com, so google.com receives the request with X-Auth header.

Comment: Aha I see. I have to work with onBeforeSendHeaders and details.requestHeaders. Alright!